# Using a this pointer in a generic lambda capture

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I have an issue in which Clang (3.6) and G++ (5.1) have a differing opinion:

```
#include <functional>

struct X
{
    X()
    {
        std::function<void (int)> f = [this](auto x){foo(x);};
    }

    void foo(int x){}
};

int main(){}
```

Clang accepts this, whereas G++ states:

```
error: cannot call member function ‘void X::foo(int)’ without object
```

Both compilers accept it if I call `this->foo(x)` directly instead, but I'd rather know who's right.

Note: both the "auto" in the lambda signature and the conversion to a std::function<> are required to trigger this case.

Comment: it compiles in [GCC 5.2](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dQyllaVrippXSDlZ)

Comment: With a gold badge and 3k+ reputation, surely you know that you have to add the main language tag to questions?!

Comment: @KerrekSB, it's obviously Pascal. I'll never understand why people feel the need to make comments like these when it doesn't stop them from answering the question. If you don't know just move on.

Comment: @Blindy: That's just silly. Without the main language tag, the question is visible to a much smaller number of people. It's in the interest of both the OP and the website that the question is actually seen by the people who are interested in it and can answer it.

Comment: @KerrekSB the question is very C++14-specific, and I would imagine most people with knowledge of C++14 have that C++14 tag on watch.  That said, I take your point and thank you for your edit.  Also, my gold badge was for a useless but popular question back in the early days, so it doesn't count ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Both compilers accept it if I call this->foo(x) directly instead, but I'd rather know who's right.

Considering it compiles in gcc 5.2, clang is the one correct in your specific case. It looks like it was just a bug in gcc 5.1. gcc 6.0 also compiles this fine.

Plus it makes intuitive sense, `this` should be implied.

Comment: I'd like to accept this, but although I'd like the "thisless" code to be correct, I don't find it intuitive: the way lambdas have been presented to us is as if it were a hidden operator() within a class that represents the lambda statement.  If you follow that line, "this->" refers to the lambda, and not the containing class.  Or perhaps I'm just overthinking it, since then that would make capturing "this" unusable.